# random forest with characters in scikit-learn/python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, ipython

I have a character column and numbers but I want to categorize the character column and apply a random forest classifier. I realize that there is OneHotEncoder but there is no example anywhere. So how can I categorize the characters e.g. a gender column which has 'f' and 'm' into integers like (0,1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) which takes an array of strings and transforms it into an array of integers.

Example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame()

data['age'] = [17,33,47]
data['gender'] = ['m','f','m']

enc = LabelEncoder()

print(data)
enc.fit(data['gender'])
data['gender'] = enc.transform(data['gender'])
print(data)
```

Output:

```
   age gender
0    17      m
1    33      f
2    47      m
   age  gender
0    17       1
1    33       0
2    47       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use [pandas's get_dummies function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html), which performs label encoding and one hot encoding.

In:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.DataFrame(list('abca'))
s = pd.get_dummies(s)
print s
```

Out:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   0   0
1   0   1   0
2   0   0   1
3   1   0   0
```